# Trying to Verify ELK installation , kibana dashboard not showing logbeats in discover tab

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-helm, elk

I used helm to load the ELK stack on kubernetes.

I ran the following commands

```
minikube start --cpus 4 --memory 8192
minikube addons enable ingress
helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
helm repo update
```

Then deployed elasticsearch

values-02.yml

```
replicas: 1
minimumMasterNodes: 1

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - host: es-elk.s9.devopscloud.link #Change the hostname to the one you need
      paths:
        - path: /
  
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Applied it

```
helm install elk-elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f values-02.yml
```

Then deployed kibana values-03.yml

```
elasticsearchHosts: "http://elasticsearch-master:9200"
ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: "nginx"
  hosts:
    - host:
      paths:
        - path: /
```

Applied it

```
 helm install elk-kibana elastic/kibana -f values-03.yml
```

Then deployed logstash

```
persistence:
  enabled: true

logstashConfig:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: 0.0.0.0
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false

logstashPipeline: 
 logstash.conf: |
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://elasticsearch-master.logging.svc.cluster.local:9200"
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
      }
    }

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: beats
      port: 5044
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5044
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
```

Applied it

```
helm install elk-logstash elastic/logstash -f values-04.yaml
```

Then deployed filebeat values-05.yaml

```
daemonset:
  filebeatConfig:
    filebeat.yml: |
      filebeat.inputs:
      - type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*.log
        processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"

      output.logstash:
        hosts: ["elk-logstash-logstash:5044"]
```

Then applied it

```
helm install elk-filebeat elastic/filebeat -f values-05.yaml
```

All up and running

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-master-0               1/1     Running   0          61m
elk-filebeat-filebeat-ggjhc          1/1     Running   0          45m
elk-kibana-kibana-6d658894bf-grb8x   1/1     Running   0          52m
elk-logstash-logstash-0              1/1     Running   0          47m
```

But when I go onto the discover page

```
http://172.21.95.140/app/management/kibana/indexPatterns?bannerMessage=To%20visualize%20and%20explore%20data%20in%20Kibana,%20you%20must%20create%20an%20index%20pattern%20to%20retrieve%20data%20from%20Elasticsearch.
```

It does not show anything, for filebeats
Instead I get a Ready to try Kibana? First, you need data message.

I was following this tutorial

https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-deploy-elk-stack-on-kubernetes/#deploy-elastic-search

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/LianDuanTrain/Helm3/blob/master/3%20Helm%20Deep%20Dive/3-12%20Use%20Helm%203%20to%20Install%20ELK%20Stack%20on%20MiniKube%20in%2010%20Mins.md) and ran the default kibana and filebeat yaml files.